# fetch all articles from google url

Tags: javascript, php

My goal is to retrieve all the divs with a given class and it works with the code below. The only problem is that the URL automatically reloads when scrolling the page. So these divs which are added when scrolling are not supported so they are not retrieved by the codes below. If anyone can help me out so that I can retrieve even the divs that appear after scrolling.`

```php
  <?php 

    $url = 'https://news.google.com/search?q=site%3A*.cd&hl=fr&gl=FR&ceid=FR%3Afr';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);//Must change the date
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    //$news = json_decode($output);
    //print_r($output);
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
                   
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $classname="NiLAwe y6IFtc R7GTQ keNKEd j7vNaf nID9nc";
    $elements = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        //print_r($element);
        //echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";
        //$x = @$dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$element));
        //$a = $x->getElementsByTagName('a');
        //var_dump($a);
        //var_dump($element);
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
          //echo "<br/>[". $node->nodeName. "]";
          if($node->nodeName == "a"){
            echo '<br/>'.$node->getAttribute('href');//link infos
            $a = $node->childNodes;
            foreach($a as $href){
              echo '<br/>'.$href->getAttribute('src');
            }
          }
        }
      }
   curl_close($ch)

;
?>
```

Comment: There's [https://serpstack.com](https://serpstack.com/), allowing a 100 searches per month for free.

Comment: Yes, but 100 searches per month is not enough for an application. This is how I am trying to solve the problem that I mentioned above. thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with JavaScript and php

first there is a function in php

```
preg_match_all();
```

You can use this along with a JavaScript or Jquery like this:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){

var search = $(“parent_div”).html();

$.ajax({
type:”POST”,
url:ur_php_file_url,
data:search,
success:function(r){
console.log(r);
}

});

});
```

And in your php file to get the divs

You can use the preg_match_all() function like this

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST[‘search’])){

preg_match_all(|<div class=“your_target_class_name(.*?)<\/div>|s, $_POST[‘search’],$match){
if(is_array($match)){
echo json_encode($match);
}
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, where should I put the jQuery codes because I only have one php file. And then where should I point the URL in the jQuery code to Google? Regards

Comment: You can create another php file and name it action.php, so that’s why all the php action takes places and on the main file you can leave the JavaScript there. So your index file will be referencing to the action.php